# How can i revert sudo make install?

Tags: wireless, drivers

How can I revert the following: (running  Kubuntu 14.10)

This is what I did before my WiFi and LAN both got their untimely death.

I did a:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

After that, I compiled and install the driver as follows -

1. Download the latest backported driver package from [here](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~...tml/backports/)
2. Copy the downloaded tar.bz2 package to your Ubuntu Desktop > Right-click > Extract here.
3. Open a terminal and run the following commands one-by-one:

   ```
   cd Desktop/backports-3.18-rc1-1
   make defconfig-ath9k
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: Note you may be able to use [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy as

```
cd Desktop/backports-3.18-rc1-1
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot.

Comment: Your answer was the perfect solution. Thanks million times. John